# If views catches error, reload page and display error

Tags: django

I don't know if this is possible with Django or not, but here's my question.

I have a form where users submit some stuff, and I want to know if I can catch an error in my views and then reload the page using the original template and throw the error in there, so the user can see it?

I have some code that returns the error I want to display, but is it possible to redirect to the original template of my view and insert this error code into there **IF** the form fails?

Bear in mind that `roundup` isnt value a user submits, but a value that is calculated from some other python code.

`if roundup >= 1:
      return HttpResponse("Price too low!")`

Comment: Where is your form code? Where is your view code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the error to your form in this way

```
if roundup >= 1:
     form.add_error(None, "Price too low!")
     return render(request, 'your_template', {'form': form})
```

and to show it the error in your template

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
     <div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
         {{ error }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My `roundup` code is calculated from 3 different input values from my form after submitted. Is this still possible?

Comment: If, assuming that the values ​​within your form are correct and that the error occurs when calculating your `roundup`, simply add the code inside `form.is_valid()`